# Creating a derived field based on df value comparison in python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

I have 2 dataframes - one is a data source dataframe and another is reference dataframe.
I want to create an additional column in df1 based on the comparison of those 2 dataframes

df1 - data source

```
No | Name
213344 | Apple
242342 | Orange
234234 | Pineapple
```

df2 - reference table

```
RGE_FROM | RGE_TO | Value
2100 | 2190 | Sweet
2200 | 2322 | Bitter
2400 | 5000 | Neutral
```

final
if first 4 character of df1.No fall between the range of df2.RGE_FROM to df2.RGE_TO, get df2.Value for the derived column df.DESC. else, blank

```
No | Name | DESC
213344 | Apple | Sweet
242342 | Orange | Natural
234234 | Pineapple |
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

We can create an `IntervalIndex` from the columns `RGE_FROM` and `RGE_TO`, then set this as an index of column `Value` to create a mapping series, then slice the first four characters in the column `No` and using `Series.map` substitute the values from the mapping series.

```
i =  pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['RGE_FROM'], df2['RGE_TO'], closed='both')
df1['Value'] = df1['No'].astype(str).str[:4].astype(int).map(df2.set_index(i)['Value'])
```

---

```
       No       Name    Value
0  213344      Apple    Sweet
1  242342     Orange  Neutral
2  234234  Pineapple      NaN
```

Comment: Question: How does Series.map know to use IntervalIndex as key instead of int when the series type is actually int? Probably the map implementation looks at the index type see if its IntervalIndex, looks if the int falls in the range and maps it?

Comment: @SomeDude Exactly right! In order to substitute values normally mapping operation matches the values in the column to the corresponding matching index values in the mapping series. But in case if the index of mapping series is `IntervalIndex`  then the map operation tries to match the values in the column which falls in the interval range.

Comment: Hi @ShubhamSharma! Thank you for your response. I am getting the error - "Category, Object, and String Subtypes are not supported for IntervalIndex"

Comment: @yuzu We need to change the data types of columns RGE_FROM and RGE_TO to integer type before creating an interval index from them.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, i am having trouble converting it to integer type. 
df2['RGE_FROM'].astype(int). is it the correct way?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma found the solution to y previous qn. got a new error - left side of interval must be <= right side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231971/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-yuzu).